# Error Details without Stack Trace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my MVC WebApi service, when an exception is thrown, it is handled by a filter:

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) {
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                                                               "Bad Request", 
                                                               context.Exception);
    } 
}
```

This HTTP response generated by this filter is dependent on config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy configuration.

If I set `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` to `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always`, all the details are serialized into the HTTP response (`Message`, `ExceptionMessage`, `ExceptionType`, and `StackTrace`).

If I set `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` to `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Never`, only the `Message` is included.

However, I want to include the `Message`, `ExceptionMessage`, and `ExceptionType` in the HTTP response but not the `StackTrace`; how do I exclude only the `StackTrace`?  Or should I just concatenate the needed details into the Message field?

To add some context to my question, the client needs these exception details to handle special cases...but never the stack trace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Leon.  Your link inspired my solution below.  It keeps the functionality of the `CreateErrorResponse` method and appends the `ExceptionMessage` and `ExceptionType` attributes.

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) {
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                                                               "Bad Request", 
                                                               context.Exception);
            var httpError = (HttpError)((ObjectContent<HttpError>)context.Response.Content).Value;
            if (!httpError.ContainsKey("ExceptionType"))
                httpError.Add("ExceptionType", context.Exception.GetType().FullName);
            if (!httpError.ContainsKey("ExceptionMessage"))
                httpError.Add("ExceptionMessage", context.Exception.Message);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Good! Nice to see it eventually worked out - always better to see a solution like this and not concatenating strings somewhere.. :)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I agree, makes for fragile code.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: But this does not include `InnerException`. And `InnerException` of `InnerException`

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate: no

Override and extend: yes

Take a look at the accepted answer here: [Return custom error objects in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243021/return-custom-error-objects-in-web-api)

and more information (in general) here: [Throw HttpResponseException or return Request.CreateErrorResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519561/throw-httpresponseexception-or-return-request-createerrorresponse)

Comment: So basically, I have to re-implement the CreateErrorResponse method and consider the IncludeErrorDetailPolicy options.  I was hope for a configuration somewhere.

Comment: Actually no. See the valid answer in the link I've given. Create a new filter. Register that filter and bind your class to that new filter. The filter will *filter* your message before it's being used. :: public class GlobalExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute >> becomes public class GlobalExceptionFilter : MyNewFilterAttributeThingyHere

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my goal.  I don't want the HTTP response to contain custom exception attributes.  Rather, I want it to work like the `CreateErrorResponse` method but with always include `ExceptionMessage`, `ExceptionType` attributes.